# URL check in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am a novice in actionscript. I am trying to make an if condition for URL check. I want to call a method if a string contains a URL:

Regular expression

```
var pattern:RegExp = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&\/~\+#])?/;
```

**Pseudo code**

```
if(string.contains(pattern)){
//do something
}
```

How can make this if condition in actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate a URL/(any String) in actionscript by using `RegExpValidator`, there are lots of way to validate data(string) but it is best way to validate all data(string). it follow all the concept of javascript's `RegExp`
 you can learn more about `RegExpValidator` on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/RegExpValidator.htm, Check this url

Also its live demo of regular Expression in actionscript

- http://www.regexr.com/
- http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start
- http://probertson.com/resources/projects/actionscript-regexp-test/RegExpTestHarness.html

may any of the one will help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for the references. Do you know how I can make this IF condition? Could you fix my pseudo code?

Comment: Its another Method but you can do it by this one also
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("YOUR_PATTER_STRING");

if(pattern.test(string)){//DO_YOUR_CODE_FOR_CORRECT_MATCH}
else{//DO_YOUR_CODE_FOR_WRONG_MATCH}

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.search(pattern) != -1) {
    //do something
}
```

If there is no match, search returns -1.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#search%28%29